# Questions on Adaptive LASSO

Tags: r, statistics, regression, confidence-interval, lasso-regression

I have almost no experience with math or stat, but I am trying to run an Adaptive LASSO on a continuous outcome with around 200 cases and a list of around 19 variables. some of these variables have 3 categories.

My question is, how can I have confidence intervals for coefficients in R?

Does the sample size enough to use an adaptive lasso?

Do I necessarily have to have the train and test data? or I can run the adaptive lasso on all the 200 cases?

Also, my other question is on the variables with more than 2 categories. How does adaptive lasso interpret that?

Comment: Can you specify what package you're using for the lasso?

Comment: Also, in response to your second question: getting confidence intervals on regularized estimates like lasso and its extensions is very tricky.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, Ben! the package I use is the glmnet

Comment: @BenBolker so by tricky you mean it is better not to do it? Tricky in what sense?

Comment: Tricky in the sense that there are some easy ways to do it that will give you the wrong answer, and some complicated ways to do it that rely on strong assumptions and large data sets (*post-selection inference*).  What function in `glmnet` are you using? It's not obvious to me that `glmnet` has the capability to do adaptive lasso ...

Comment: @BenBolker I follow these steps:  https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/alasso